# Today as the basic date and then count Nth day's `day-week` during 5 years before and after

Tags: sql, sql-server

e.g:
If N is 13th and the basic date is today then i hope calling some function or view or sp to get `13th` day's `day-week` group count during 5 years before and after

Expected:
If today is `2020-02-03` then the expected data :

```
dayOfWeek,count
1,16
2,19
3,16
4,19
5,15
6,18
7,17
```

What i have tried :

```
declare @now date = '2020-2-3'; 
declare @TheDateBefore5Years date = dateadd(year,-5,@now) 
    ,@TheDateAfter5Years date = dateadd(year,5,@now) 
;
with cte as (
   //....
)
select dayOfWeek,count(1) count
from cte
group by dayOfWeek
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select datepart(dow, datecol), count(1) count
from t
where datecol >= dateadd(year, -5, '2020-02-03') and
      datecol <= dateadd(year, 5, '2020-02-03')
group by datepart(dow, datecol)
```

Comment: thanks,yes,the main logic is it,but i have no idea on `t`

Comment: @Wei . . . That is a placeholder for your table name, which is not specified in the question.